# retrieve the last saved attribute in a core data database

Tags: ios, database

I'm completely new to core data programming! I'm trying to write an app that is, in short, like this:

The user has a lot of data in a view, these data are the results os lots of calculations done before. in this particular "all results" view, there is an option for saving the data for future reference, to do this the user is asked to enter an identifier (in a textfield) and press the save button.

To retrieve the saved data, the user re-enter the identifier and press the load button.

Almost everything works very well: the data is being saved and loaded... But the problem is that when entering the identifier and pressing the LOAD button, the app loads the first saved data, not the last one! I want the app to load the last saved data when pressing the load button... how can I do that?

I'm very sorry to bother you with this newbie question, but this is the very first time I'm trying to deal with Core Data, and I really want to know how to do this! I thank very much everyone who can help me!

The code for the "LOAD" button is this:

```
- (IBAction)loadData:(id)sender
{
    [_identificador resignFirstResponder];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"English"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(identificador = %@)", _identificador.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0)
    {
        _status.text = @"No matches";
    }
    else
    {
        matches = objects[0];
        _dataAtualEng.text = [matches valueForKey:@"dataRCQ"];
        _rcqEng.text = [matches valueForKey:@"rcq"];
        _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lu matches found", (unsigned long)[objects count]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The objects array contains all the objects with the identifier you have specified in the predicate.

In your code you are using

```
matches = objects[0];
```

which is giving you the first saved object.

Instead you should be using

```
matches = objects.lastObject;
```

However you might want to re-think your implementation as the way to uniquely identify an entry is through its primary key (identificador in your case), which should be different for each save.

Comment: Thank you very much Vijayts!!!! And I think you're right... But in my app, I cannot force the user to enter a unique identifier for each save, my app is about physical evaluations, calculating BMI, body fat, etc... and this "All results" view is where all the results of the evaluation are shown to the user, and then he decides to save it or not... You know, the identifier is the name of the person being evaluated. But is there a way to overwrite the data if the user enter the same identifier, instead of saving another "instance" with the same identifier?

Comment: Sorry Vladimir. I am not sure of any such method. Also if the answer helped your issue. Kindly do mark it as accepted :)